# Identifying the nature of the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wish somebody could help me in this one. We have to choose one of the $4$ options.

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $b^2+c^2<a<1$. Consider the $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & b & c \\
        b & a & 0 \\
        c & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.$$

1. All the eigenvalues of $A$ are negative real numbers.
2. All the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive real numbers.
3. $A$ can have a positive as well as a negative eigenvalue.
4. Eigenvalues of $A$ can be non-real complex numbers.

Now, $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, so

$$\begin{vmatrix}
        1-\lambda & b & c \\
        b & a-\lambda & 0 \\
        c & 0 & 1-\lambda \\
        \end{vmatrix}=0$$

$\implies(1-\lambda)(a-a\lambda -\lambda +\lambda^2)-b(b-b\lambda)-c(ac-c\lambda)=0$

$\implies a-a\lambda -\lambda +\lambda^2-a\lambda+a\lambda^2 +\lambda^2 -\lambda^3-b^2+b^2\lambda-ac^2+c^2\lambda=0$

$\implies-\lambda^3+\lambda^2(2+a)+\lambda(-2a-1+b^2+c^2)+a-b^2-ac^2=0$

I am stuck here, don't know how to proceed. Need your help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the matrix is symmetric (so, we can exclude option 4 immediately), and the question basically asks if the matrix is negative definite (all eigenvalues are negative), positive definite (all eigenvalues are positive), or indefinite (we have both negative and positive eigenvalues).

Let's check the leading principal minoras:

\begin{align*}
\det A_{11} &= \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix} = 1 > 0, \\
\det A_{12} &= \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} = a - b^2 > c^2 > 0, \\
\det A_{33} &= \det A = \det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & b & c \\ b & a & 0 \\ c & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = a - ac^2 - b^2 > c^2 - ac^2 = c^2 (1-a) > 0,
\end{align*}

So, all of these are positive and we can conclude that the matrix $A$ is positive definite, i.e., option 2 is correct.

Comment: From this I can guess that a negative definite matrix would have all the leading principal minors as negative. And in case of indefinite matrix, some leading principal minors would be positive and some negative. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Negative definite matrix would have odd leading principal minoras negative, while the even ones would still be positive. You see that from the faxt that $X$ is negative definite if $-X$ is positive definite, and $\det \alpha X = (\alpha)^n X$, where $n$ is the order of $X$. So, for an even order $n = 2k$, you get $(-1)^{2k} = 1$, hence the determinant remains positive.

Comment: I know I could be sounding stupid but I'll be really grateful if you can tell me how to identify an indefinite matrix.

Comment: The criteria for the positive and the negative definite matrices is "if and only if". So, assuming that your matrix is nonsingular, if a) even-sized leading prinicpal minors are not all positive; or b) odd-sized leading prinicpal minors are not all of the same sign (all negative or all positive); your matrix is indefinite. For singular matrices, it gets more complicated (you have to observe all the principal minors, not just the leading ones).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1\quad x_2\quad x_3]^{T}$ is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then,\begin{align} \mathbf{x^T}A\mathbf{x}=&[x_1\quad x_2\quad x_3]\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b & c\\
b & a & 0\\
c & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} \\
\ =& x_1^2+x_3^2+ax_2^2+2bx_1x_2+2cx_1x_3\\
\ =& (x_1+bx_2+cx_3)^2+ax_2^2+x_3^2-(bx_2+cx_3)^2\\
\ =& (x_1+bx_2+cx_3)^2+(a-b^2)x_2^2+(1-c^2)x_3^2-2bcx_2x_3\\
\ >& (x_1+bx_2+cx_3)^2+c^2x_2^2+b^2x_3^2-2bcx_2x_3\\
\ =& (x_1+bx_2+cx_3)^2+(cx_2-bx_3)^2\ge 0
\end{align}
Hence $A$ is positive definite and also it is symmetric $\Rightarrow $ all the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive and real. So option $(2)$ is the correct one.

Comment: if it is grater and equal to zero, can it also have a zero eigenvalue? I mean for a positive definite, it should be strictly greater than zero, shouldn't it be?

Comment: But it is not just $\ge0$. You have $x^T A x = \dots \color{red}{>} \dots \ge \dots 0$, so $x^T A x > 0$.